# Load Runner :Oracle NCA & Web Multiprotocol Replay Errors

Tags: javascript

When I am replying to the script, We are getting the following error.
Error: nca_button_press(697) failed, window or object is not displayed.

We want to know how to solve this issue in this multi-protocol. And get the script fixed. Thanks in Advance